# PHP based contact form not working within Blogger

Tags: php, html, css, google-drive-api, blogger

PHP based contact form not working within Blogger

I tried to include a contact form with an add-on of uploading files (i.e. pictures) to my blog. I found PHP based solution which fits my requirements. I integrated this solution by inserting the following line to my post template

The PHP files are stored at my google drive
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz-Kaq_byIZlflpjcXBmQThUcVAyT2dsa1RaX0RGRVMtYVlKcUxoclAySldzSUt0ZlczeU0

By activating the post, I'm getting an error ('A plugin is needed to display this content').

You can try evaluate the issue by choosing the Upload item on the following blog 'http://helheimofevildoers.blogspot.de'

Unfortunately I didn't find so far any hints to solve the issue.

Can someone point me how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem will be caused as google drive doesn't support to use server based PHP scripts.

I solved the issue by following post http://officialprblogger.blogspot.de/2013/06/make-your-own-contact-form-with-file.html